# Can't make a copy of /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1

Tags: rhel, sudo, mysql, cp

I have a RedHat Linux server and I'm trying to make a copy of `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1`, but I'm receiving an error saying permission denied and the file cannot be opened.

I'm logged in as root user and tried to use `sudo cp`...

I was trying `sudo su mysql` to make the copy, then it asks for a password that should be the one I have, but it is saying it's wrong!

Comment: Are you receiving permission denied errors or open file, cannot read etc..check SELinux permissions/constructs.

Comment: I'm receiving Pessision Denied -> `cp: cannot open 'ibdata1.bak' for reading: Permission denied`

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /var/lib/mysql/ibdata.bak` and of `id`? We can see if it is a permissions issue.

Comment: If you are loged in as `root` you should not use `sudo` or `su` just run the `cp` command.

Comment: @MaxMackie, the id returned me `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel)` and the other command returned me `-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 2669674496 Dec  7 21:59 /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1.bak` (I know, it is incredibly huge, that is why is .bak, had to rename to use mysql again!)

Comment: If you're logged in as root (which you are), you won't need the `sudo` in front of the `cp` command. So try it without the `sudo`. If that doesn't work, is it possible that you're using network authentication (NIS/PAM)?

Comment: @MaxMackie, not sure if I know exactly what you are talking about! How can I find out if I'm using NIS/PAM? Currently I'm using putty to connect to my server, it's hosted at Softlayer and I'm using the default root user provided. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Oh so this isn't "your" in-house server? Alright cool. Have you tried running `cp` without `sudo` or `su` yet? Just plain old `cp /var/lib/mysql/ibdata.bak ~/ibdata.bak2` (copying to your home directory).

Comment: Hey @MaxMackie, I've tried it before and I received the following error: `cp: cannot open '/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1.bak' for reading: Permission denied`

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the directories? `ls -li /var/lib/mysql` `ls -li /var/lib` `ls -li /var`? This is a weird issue which could be attributed to disk corruoption, in which case we will need to `fsck`

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! Don't know if this matter, but for the mysql folder I have: `196729 drwxrwxrwx  17 mysql   mysql   4096 Dec 14 12:52 mysql`. For all folders and files I do have permission (*rwxrwxrwx). So how should I work with `fsck`?

Comment: `ls -Z ` output? btw, did you stop mysqld before starting to copy. On the other hand, use `rsync` with `--partial` and to make sure your data is copied from where it stopped.

Comment: FSCK didn't work also, neither rsync. Tried to restart server but didn't work also. Any other try? Thanks